# jQuery/PHP ajax contact form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have been fighting with this for quite awhile, searching questions, tutorials, and forums to not find a working solution. I'm extremely green in the realm of PHP and just now starting to learn.

Page in progress can be found here: http://williamsfuller.com/limedropdesign/

Goal: Use front end validation using jQuery Validate (http://jqueryvalidation.org/), if validation is successful then in the submitHandler run an ajax call to a php file that takes the form values and posts them to the server. On the ajax.done function clear the form and show that the submission has been successful.

***Reason I'm using ajax is because I don't want the page to refresh and send the user back to the top of the page. This is a single page portfolio and if I was to do a post method on the form it will ruin the experience by reloading the page.***

What I have achieved thus far:
-I have the jQuery validation working
-If the validation is successful the ajax call runs correctly activating the contact form submission file
-On the ajax.done function the contact form clears and a success message slides down telling the user the message has been sent
-On the php side of things I was able to hardcode a mail function that runs which tells me that the ajax call is working and the php file is working.

```
<?php    
mail('email@gmail.com', 'Mail from Lime Drop Design', 'some body content for the email ');
?>
```

Where I'm stuck is taking the jQuery values and putting them into a working if($_POST){} and having that send off an email.

***I also have a honey pot in the form to catch some bots, if all the information is validated and the subject field is still filled out I'm looking to just allow the POST to die.***

HTML:

```
<form id="contactForm" method="get" action="">
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control"
           type="text"
           name="name"
           id="name"
           minlength="2"
           placeholder="Name" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control"
           type="email"
           name="email"
           id="email"
           placeholder="Your email address" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control contactMessage"
              name="message"
              id="message"
              rows="8"
              minlength="10"
              placeholder="Enter a message" required></textarea>
</div>

<input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" autocomplete="off">

<div class="form-actions">
    <input type="hidden" name="save" value="contact">
    <button id="formSubmit" type="submit" class="btn contact-btn pull-right">Send</button>
</div>
<div id="result">
    Thank you, your message has been sent to Liz!
</div>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#result').hide();
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        submitHandler: function() {
            var nameValue = $('#name').val();
            var emailValue = $('#email').val();
            var messageValue = $('#message').val();
            console.log(nameValue, emailValue, messageValue);
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "contactSubmission.php",
                data: {
                    name: $('#name').val(),
                    email: $('#email').val(),
                    message: $('#messageValue').val()
                }
            }).done(function(){
                $('#contactForm').find("input[type=text], input[type=email], textarea").val("");
                $('#result').slideDown();
            });
        }
    });
    $("#contactForm").validate();
)};
```

PHP Working:

```
<?php
mail('email@gmail.com', 'Mail from Lime Drop Design', 'some body content for the email outisde post function');
?>
```

PHP not working (what I'm trying to achieve):

```
<?php
if($_POST){
$to = 'email@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Contact Form Submission';
$message = $_POST['messageValue'];


if($_POST['subject'] != ''){
    die();
}

//Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
$nameValue        = filter_var($_POST["nameValue"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$emailValue       = filter_var($_POST["emailValue"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$messageValue     = filter_var($_POST["messageValue"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

mail($to, $subject, $message);
}
?>
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. I have been trying to get this to work for awhile now and I seem to just be stuck on the php POST at this point. Thanks in advance for any input or working example.

Comment: Does php send any error?

Comment: I don't know php but in jQuery you are using get and php you are using post????

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, seeing some emails now coming in. Currently I have the hardcoded version in so at least something was working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out, you're making a GET request with Jquery while php expect a POST one.

Then on your php, the post fields aren't good: You put 'Value' post field:
`$_POST["nameValue"]` while on Jquery it seems like the field is named `name`, try changing `$_POST["nameValue"]` to `$_POST["name"]` And do the same for message and email.

EDIT : Change `$('#messageValue').val()` to `$('#message').val()` in the post datas in your Jquery code, this value was the reason why the data wasn't succefully sent to PHP, in you console.log you've put the right ID but not in the post data, that's why you where thinking the correct values was sent by php.

Comment: This is on the right track :). 
Changed the ajax call to: 'type: "POST",' and I got rid of all the **Value** from filter_var($_POST[nameValue] and that all works. The only thing I'm not getting is the Form Values for all of the fields.

Comment: How do you check for the value? and where you don't get them? On the php or on the jquery?

Comment: I run a console.log with $('#name').val(), email, and message. I run that in the submitHandler function. So once validation is successful those values will print in console. When I receive an email I'm not getting the inputted name, email, or message.

Comment: And the values printed on the console are the good ones? Then in the mail you receive what are the values?

Comment: Correct, whatever I enter into the fields as long as it passes validation will show up in the console and is what I want to hand over to the PHP file. The emails will be sent to the correct address, the hardcoded "Contact Form Submission" for the subject line shows up, but content will be empty. What I would like to do is just print the values (name field, email field, and message) into the body of the email.

Comment: Then after sanitize the data, try to add the line `$message = $nameValue . ' ' .$emailValue.' '.$messageValue;`

Comment: Thanks, the name and email fields are now both showing up in a sent email. However the message is still not displaying.

Comment: What if you try not to sanitize him? by putting the raw $_POST['message'] instead of the $messageValue? EDIT: I edited my post, keep the sanitized date ;)

Comment: So tried this a couple ways. At first did $messageValue = filter_var($_POST["message"]; and that didn't work. Tried using the raw $messageValue = $_POST["message"]; and that didn't work either. Wondering if since it's a textarea it needs something special.